# SSRS export to xml using specific name of elements

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to create this xml using ssrs

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <catalog>
       <book idNum="2">
          <author name="Kim" surname="Ralls">
             <title nameT="XML Developer's Guide" position="32"/>
             <publish_date="2000-10-01" description="An in-depth look at creating applications"/>
          </author>
          <author name="Kim" surname="Ralls1">
             <title nameT="Fantasy" position="31"/>
             <publish_date="2000-10-01" description="A former architect battles corporate zombies"/>
          </author>
       </book>
        <book idNum="1">
          <author name="Eva" surname="Corets">
             <title nameT="Maeve" position="23"/>
             <publish_date="2001-11-01" description="After the collapse of a nanotechnology "/>
          <author>
       </book>
    </catalog>
```

Is there a way to insert the data into the table in such a way that when I export it to xml I get this structure as in the example?
I tried using the matrix table in SSRS Builder Reporting, but I failed to get this format.
can anyone help me, please?

Comment: I'm not sure you're quite going to get the level of control over SSRS's XML output that you would need to dictate the entire XML document's structure.  You specifically need this to come from SSRS?  Depending on the actual use of the XML, you might find it easier to just output the full XML as a single "string" value from SQL Server itself, and just display that in a single text-field on a report.  Even then, downloading that as, say, CSV, is not just going to give you a file, straight away, that has only your XML document in it